# Inserting data in database using DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am using VS 2010 and service based database and Vb.net

I want to insert data into database using DataGridView. Although, all the rows present in DataGridView are inserted in database but additional row is also inserted at the start containing ID as "0" and leaving other columns blank which I don,t want at all.

I have attached the Code and Database table for your review.
please help me to get out of this problem,

```
Dim Sql_ConnectionString = " DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\databaseapplication\DataGridView\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.mdf;IntegratedSecurity=True;User Instance=True"[Database Table Pic][1]

        Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            Dim dataAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter


            con.ConnectionString = Sql_ConnectionString
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table4 (ID,Name,Marks) values ('" + row.Cells("cus_ID").Value + "','" + row.Cells("cus_Name").Value + "','" + row.Cells("cus_Marks").Value + "')"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

            con.Close()
```

Comment: if `AllowUsersToAddRows` is true, you are looping thru one too many rows.  If the ID is a proper DB ID, you should not have to specify it; there is plenty more to fix as well, starting with disposing of DBObjects

Comment: I would suggest doing it differently.  Create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid.  You can then use a data adapter to save the entire contents of the table to the database in one `Update` call, without any need for a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Jmcilhinney, you are true but what if we have more than one DataGridView? Do we need to create datatable for each of them? Or is there any way else to get out of this problem?

Comment: Plutonix, thanks for the reply! Can you help how can i fix this problem?